# Jquery UI slider events not working Drupal 7

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, drupal, drupal-7

I am trying to implement a slider for a view form ( i have hidden the text field and want to make a script to display a slider and on change / stop to set the value to hidden text field. My problem is that the events are not firing at all. I added the jquery UI library and my script in the template.php of my template ( using ZEN ) :

```
function ThemeName_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  drupal_add_library('system', 'ui');
  drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.slider');
  drupal_add_js('URL/js/search.js');
}
```

and this is the javascript/jquery code :

```
(function ($, Drupal, window, document, undefined) {
  Drupal.behaviors.customSearch = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
        $(document).ready(function (){
          $("#distanta_slider").slider({
                orientation: "horizontal",
                range: "min",
                max: 150,
                min: 1,
                value: 1,
                //change: slider_change(),
                //slide: slider_change(),
                //stop: slider_change()
            });
            $("#distanta_slider").on("slidestop",slider_change());
            $("#distanta_slider").on("slide",slider_change());
            $("#distanta_slider").on("slidechange",slider_change());
            });
        function slider_change(){
            alert($("#distanta_slider").slider("value"));
        }
      }
  };
})(jQuery, Drupal, this, this.document);
```

I tried binding the event using $(selector).on , and also tried to declare them in the constructor ( the 3 commented lines ). In the first scenario at page load i received 3 alerts with the current value , in the second scenario i receive 3 alerts saying "Object Object" , but in both scenarios if I move the slider absolutely nothing happens ... No errors , nothing .

Any help is most appreciated. Thank you in advance,

Cristi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call function name without arguments in on statement.

```
 $("#distanta_slider").on("slidestop",slider_change);
 $("#distanta_slider").on("slide",slider_change);
 $("#distanta_slider").on("slidechange",slider_change);
```

Wrong Assumption

```
$("#distanta_slider").on("slidestop",slider_change());
```

the function slider_change executes immediately here

Comment: Unbelievable... It was that simple .... I am an idiot . Thank you very much for the help .

Comment: Glad to help you Cristi